# PHP Telegram bot HTTP request failed running running 000webhost.com server with SSL subdomain

Tags: php, bots, web-hosting, host, telegram

I basically wrote my script on PHP and I uploaded to my 000webhost servers. Here is the code and the following are the errors. I tried to use Apache servers and it gave me the same error. I then uploaded my php script into my 000webhost pubic_html folder and it still gives me the same errors.

```
 <?php

 ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

 $botToken = "";
 $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

 $update = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $update = json_decode($update, TRUE);

 $chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
 $message = $update["message"]["text"];

 switch($message) {

 case "/test":
 sendMessage($chatId, "test");
 break;
 case "/hi":
 sendMessage($chatId, "hey there!");
 break;
 default:
sendMessage($chatId, "default");

 }

 function sendMessage ($chatId, $message) {

$url= $GLOBALS['website']."/sendMessagechat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message);
file_get_contents($url);
 }

 ?>
```

This is my error.

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot/getupdates): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in /storage/ssd3/923/2305923/public_html/Socializersbot.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function jason_decode() in /storage/ssd3/923/2305923/public_html/Socializersbot.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd3/923/2305923/public_html/Socializersbot.php on line 9

Comment: The second error is easy, it's `json_decode()` not `jason_decode()`, the first one - are you sure you have authorisation to view that page?

Comment: Yes I do its my API token that I created

Comment: Why you didn't put $website in the file_get_contents () ?

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me

```
<?php

 ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

 $botToken = "{yourToken}";
 $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

 $update = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $update = json_decode($update, TRUE);

 $chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
 $message = $update["message"]["text"];

 switch($message) {

 case "/test":
 sendMessage($chatId, "test");
 break;
 case "/hi":
 sendMessage($chatId, "hey there!");
 break;
 default:
sendMessage($chatId, "default");

 }

 function sendMessage ($chatId, $message) {

$url= $GLOBALS['website']."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message);
file_get_contents($url);
 }

 ?>
```